# How do i disable a button GameObject after clicking it. In other words, have a button that is only clickable ONCE

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an upgrade button for a game I'm creating, obviously I want the upgrade to only be available once, how do I code that?

I looked around the internet and each person suggested trying the following:

`Bouton.SetActive (false);`

or something like that. However, this makes the button inactive during startup. I want it to be inactive or destroyed after just one click. the button in question must be a GameObject

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

```html
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class One_One_Click_to_Save_the_GameObject_Deactivate_If_scene_replay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Bouton;
    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("buttonState")) // if the button was saved in memory
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("buttonState") == 0) //if the value is 0
                Bouton.SetActive (false); // make button disabled
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buttonState", 1); // saving in memory that button is on
        }

    }

    public void buttonCliked()
    {
        Bouton.SetActive(false); // making the button disabled
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buttonState", 0); //saving in memory that button is off 
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you set `Bouton.SetActive(false);` only in the `buttonCliked()` method? The problem might be that during startup you do not have the `buttonState` set to `1`.

Comment: How to set button State parameter? i could have a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not have any code piece to reset the state of your button on PlayerPrefs.

You should go to `Edit -> Clear All PlayerPrefs` on Unity Editor to get rid of the previous saved states.

Then you will check if the player is already used the upgrade button which you did on start but you dont need the else statement because in default it will be already active on the scene so this should be enough

```
    void Start()
    {
         if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("buttonState")) // if the button was saved in memory
         {
              if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("buttonState") == 0) //if the value is 0
              Bouton.SetActive (false); // make button disabled
         }
    }
```

Alternatively you can use the `PlayerPrefs.GetInt()` method with a default parameter so you don't need to check if it has a key, like this

```
void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("buttonState",1) == 0) // This will return 1 if there is no key with the name "buttonState"
        Bouton.SetActive (false);
    }
```

And after you clicked the upgrade which you should be doing on your `buttonCliked()` method. You can set the buttonstate to zero and it will always disable it on start. If you want to reset the state you need to clear the player prefs again like we did it on first step

```
public void buttonCliked()
{
    Bouton.SetActive(false); // making the button disabled
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buttonState", 0); //saving in memory that button is off 
}
```

But again alternatively you can disable the clicking function on the button rather than just disabling it on the menu. What you should do is create a Button reference rather than a gameobject (or get the button component on the gameobject) and set it's interactable field to false. Which makes the button not clickable but still be seen on the screen.

You can use `public Button Bouton;` rather than `public GameObject Bouton;`and instead of using `Bouton.SetActive (false);` you can now call `Bouton.interactable = false;`

Comment: thanks for all it's been a few months since i was stuck on this problem. I have another question and is it possible to do the same with three Gameobjects reverse situation three disabled buttons and when we click on an already enabled Gameobject it activates all three disabled buttons?

Comment: here once the Accept button is clicked, everything must remain enabled except the PanelButton it must remain disabled once the scene is replayed

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response I was away for a while. I did not quite understand what you are trying to achive with the reverse situation. Can you be more specific?